# istream::getline failbit not getting set?

Tags: c++, c++11, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    istringstream input("1234");
    char c[5];

    while(input.getline(c, 5, '\n')){
        cout << "OUTPUT: " << c << endl;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
OUTPUT: 1234
```

When all sources tell me `input` should test as `false` and there should be no output. From the standard (N3337) [27.7.2.3]/18:

> Effects: Behaves as an unformatted input function (as described in 27.7.2.3, paragraph 1). After constructing a sentry object, extracts characters and stores them into successive locations of an array whose first element is designated by s. Characters are extracted and stored until one of the following
> occurs:

> 1. end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls setstate(eofbit));
>    2. traits::eq(c, delim) for the next available input character c (in which case the input character
>    is extracted but not stored);320
>    3. n is less than one or **n - 1 characters are stored** (in which case the function calls setstate(
>    failbit)).

Since `4` values get stored, `failbit` should be getting set. Some other sources give a bit different but confusing input on this function. [Cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/):

> The failbit flag is set if the function extracts no characters, or if the delimiting character is not found once (n-1) characters have already been written to s. Note that if the character that follows those (n-1) characters in the input sequence is precisely the delimiting character, it is also extracted and the failbit flag is not set (the extracted sequence was exactly n characters long).

Again, the delimiting character `'\n'` is not found after the `4`, and so `failbit` should be getting set. [Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) says a similar thing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it reads `n-1` characters and it never encountered `'\n'` but you missed the first point

> end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function calls setstate(eofbit));

Since you read in exactly what was in the stream the `eofbit` gets set and you get the input.

If we add

```
std::cout << input.eof();
```

You can see that is indeed what happened([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f1b250dd7cc48bb))

Comment: I was not aware setting only `eofbit` meant `input` still tested as true. I'm reading from C++ Primer and these are its words: _If any of
badbit, failbit, or eofbit are set, then a condition that evaluates that stream will fail._ (chapter 8.1.2). But, looking up, it seems only `badbit` or `failbit` need to be set.

Comment: @SergeantPenguin The stream will evaluate to true if only the EOF flag is true.  See the table at the bottom the this page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good